# How to iterate through list of objects in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Hi friends i am trying iterate through a list that contains list of objects
I am trying to iterate through that list . each element of the list is a 'object'. 
I accessing the variables of that 'object' with the help of c:forEach . I am getting the values. but the same again and again . 
I dont know if i am doing any mistake while adding objects to list in the servlet or in the jsp while iterating through them.

Here is my servlet code

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo();
            List<FileInfo> fileInfoList = new ArrayList<FileInfo>();

            HashMap<String, String> uploadHistory = new HashMap<String, String>();

            while(rs.next()) {

                fileInfo.setFile_id(rs.getString("file_id"));
                fileInfo.setFile_name(rs.getString("file_name"));
                fileInfo.setUpload_time(rs.getString("upload_time"));
                fileInfo.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));     

                fileInfoList.add(fileInfo);

                uploadHistory.put(rs.getString("file_name"),rs.getString("upload_time"));
            }

            request.setAttribute("uploadHistory",uploadHistory);
            request.setAttribute("fileInfo",fileInfo);
            request.setAttribute("fileInfoList", fileInfoList);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/UploadHistoryJsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
```

Here is my jsp

```
<div class="panel-body">
                    <table id="uploadHistoryTable" class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th><strong>File Name</strong></th>
                            <th><strong>Date & Time</strong></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>

                            <c:forEach var="uploaded" items="${fileInfoList}">
                            <tr>

                                <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/DownloadServlet?f=${uploaded.file_name}&p=${uploaded.username}">${uploaded.file_name}</a></td>
                                <td>${uploaded.upload_time}</td>
                            </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- panel-body -->
```

Please help . Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: You're always updating just a single instance of `FileInfo`. Just move this line `FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo();` inside while loop, so that a new object before adding that to map

Comment: @Arkantos is right...thats the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this line: `FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo();` within the `while` loop:

```
while(rs.next()) {
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo();
....
```

As is, you are creating only one instance and keep updating the same. Most likely you keep on seeing the last element you are pulling from the database multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding same object again and again. You need to initiate `FileInfo` inside while loop

```
  while(rs.next()) {
     FileInfo fileInfo= new FileInfo();
          .....
     fileInfoList.add(fileInfo)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is you're always updating a single instance of FileInfo through `fileInfo` variable, so in each iteration you're just overwriting a single object's state.

```
   FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo();
   --------
    while(rs.next()) {
      // updating fileInfo from result set
   }
```

Move that `FileInfo` into the while loop like below

```
   while(rs.next()) {
      FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo();
      // update new fileInfo from result set and add to fileInfoList
   }
```